# Test method not run with sequence in testng

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am using TestNG + WebDriver for my automation project but order of test execution is not working as expected have specified the order for each method below is the method signature and notation

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods="verifyElementsOnProfileScreen",alwaysRun = true)
    public void verifyMySelfProfileVisibility(){
```

TestSuit the I have using :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="regressionSuite" parallel="none">

  <parameter name="ApplicationOpt" value="web"></parameter>
  <parameter name="Browser" value="firefox"></parameter>

  <test name="Test">    
    <classes>
        <!-- Login Module -->
      <class name="Tests.Login.LoginApp"/>
        <method>
            <include name ="loginUser"></include>
        </method>

        <!-- Portal Module -->  
         <class name="Tests.Profile.ProfileModule">
            <method>
                <include name="verifyElementsOnProfileScreen"></include>
                <include name="verifyMySelfProfileVisibility"></include>
            </method>
        </class>
        <class name="Tests.Profile.participantAuditLog">
         <method>
            <include name="verifyAuditLogForCreateProfileEvent"></include>
            <include name="verifyAuditLogForUpdateContactInfoEvnet"></include>
            <include name="verifyAuditLogForUpdatePrivacyDirective"></include>
        </method>
     </class>

    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- regressionSuite -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean Classes which specified in testng.xml file not executing in specified order.. then please use preserve-order= "true"

```
 <suite name="MySuite" preserve-order= "true">
 <test name="MyTest">
```

If you want to specify order of methods execution in Class then use priority

```
@Test( priority = 1 )
```

group-by-instances="true" also useful if you face situation like execution order of priority methods of different classes are not as expected..

```
 <suite thread-count="2" verbose="10" name="testSuite" parallel="tests">
 <test verbose="2" name="MytestCase" group-by-instances="true">
```

Thank You,
Murali